# Set first day of week in momentjs - isoWeek

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is it possible to set the first day of the week on Saturday for type isoweek?

I want to get isoWeek number for first day of week is Saturday. But default in moment first day in isoWeek is Monday.

I try something:

```
moment.lang('en', {week: {dow: 6, doy: 4}});
```

but its work fine only for `week()` (Saturday is first day of week):

```
moment(date).week()
```

for method `isoWeek()` its not working, becouse Monday is still first day of week.

maybe somebody know a different way of getting the week number, where the first day of the week is Saturday and is used standard ISO 8601.

Comment: The ISO8601 standard specifies firmly that weeks start on Monday.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). If you want to deviate from that, you have the `week` option, as you showed.  Changing `isoWeek` makes no sense.  That's what it's there for.

Comment: hmm, maybe you have right, but i need to algoritm from `isoWeek` to calculate number of week. from method `week()` i get wrong value. isoWeek has the assumption "first week contains first thursday.".

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The `isoWeek` functionality is intended to align exactly with the ISO8601 week definition, including that the first week contains the first Thursday.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week

Comment: Basically, you should use `week` and not `isoWeek` unless you want the behavior of an ISO week.